Introduction to the Shelah
Can someone recommend a sefer or article that discuss the creation of the work "Shenei Luchos HaBris" by Rabbi Yeshayahu Horowitz? The only thing I found, was written by the Chida, in his Shem HaGedolim.

Why did the Shelah write this sefer?
What is the structure of the sefer?
Was the Shelah influenced by a specific teacher? What was his specific style?

For example, I am aware of the Torah Ohr-section, but there is also "Toldos Adam", "Asara Maamaros" etc.. What is the theme of these sections?
Is there any information about this sefer? Please do not refer to wikipedia or sorts. Please cite good sources, like a sefer "Shem HaGedolim".

The Baal HaTanya based much of his teachings on the Shalah. You would do well to pursue Chabad sources on this.

@RabbiKaii Thanks Reb Kaii. I did notice that Chabad-sources tend to cite the Shaloh often. Wondered why. Maybe the Baal Shem Tov was influenced by the Shaloh?

He certainly was. The Shalah's work was in the tradition and chain of teachings stretching from Zohar, through Arizal, to the Baal Shem Tov. They are very much a singular line of teaching. However, more specifically, the Tanya was heavily influenced by the Shalah in particular, and the Rebbe quotes the Shalah a lot.

I have this book at home: Life and Teachings of Isaiah Horowitz by Rabbi Eugene Newman, published 1972
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Teachings-Isaiah-Horowitz-Eugene-Newman/dp/0900517190

I can post more information about it tomorrow.
Apologies for the delay in posting this - I have now found the book




@Shmuel Apologies for the delay in posting this - I have now found the book and added the photos above

Thanks. I guess p. 74 does answer my question. Would you be able to answer my question based on that perhaps? :)
