Tanya is based on Shelah?
I came across a statement in this answer (also reflected in these comments) that piqued my curiosity:

the Tanya is based heavily on the Shalah's work

Is that true? In what sense? Where can I learn more about it?

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/143354/27180

Just reading the shalah, the parallels are striking.

@Yishai Any specific parts?

@shmosel As I remember, it is sprinkled all over. I would be reading parts and it was like I was just reading an expanded version of Tanya on the subject. They don't always agree on the details, but the structure of the topic runs in parallel. The contrast about the meaning of Dira BeTachtonim was interesting.

This is long standing tradition in chabad and is explained in the English translation with commentary known as Lessons In Tanya. Here is the quote that comes in the beginning of the book shortly after the title... (https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/61092/jewish/Title-Page.htm)

In his modesty, the Alter Rebbe named the book Likkutei Amarim—“A
Compilation of Teachings,” claiming that he did no more than collect
teachings “from books and teachers.” Chasidic tradition understands
“books” as a reference to the works of the Maharal and the Shaloh, and
“teachers” as the Baal Shem Tov and the Maggid of Mezritch.

